# Updating field in Database with if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am working on recieveing an item from another application with the use of $_POST and I am trying to see if that item already exists in the database. If it does, then $count increases by one. If it does not exist in the database, then it will added in with the use of INSERT INTO.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
   $today = date('m-d-Y');
   echo $today;

   $con= mysqli_connect("******","******","******") 
       or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
   mysqli_select_db($con,"a3656574_opacmin");
   $sql= "SELECT keyWord FROM searchedWords";
   $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   if($result==$_POST[keyWord])
   {
       $upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1";
          while (!mysqli_query($con,$upD))
        {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
   }
   else
   {
      $insertIn="INSERT INTO `searchedWords`( `keyWord`, `countr`) values ('$_POST[keyWord]',1)";
    while (!mysqli_query($con,$insertIn))
        {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
   }
?>
```

I don't know what's wrong. No items are sent to the database at all. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Just FYI... You should reconsider posting your password on a public website

Comment: Remove your credentials! What do you expect $result to be? Why would it be equal to $_POST[keyword] ? What is keyWord?

Comment: Hint: You'll need a loop in there....

Comment: `$result==$_POST[keyWord]` it will always return false because `$result` has query object not the data from query

Comment: that's not the real password. :) $_POST[keyword] contains a string from another application for Android. The mobile application passes the keyword to the site, then stores this in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this...

```
 $result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT keyWord FROM searchedWords");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  if($row['keyWord']==$_POST[keyWord])
 {
   $upD="UPDATE searchedWords SET countr = countr + 1";
      while (!mysqli_query($con,$upD))
    {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
 }
```

**$result==$_POST['keyWord']** won't work becase $result is object there so...

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
$result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

You have to fetch the data

```
  $keyword = '';
/* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $keyword =  $row["keyWord"];
    }
```